# Intergral of sequence of functions that converge pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I came across the following problem in my Prof's Analysis 1 notes:

> Let $\, f_n : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise, i.e., $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Does $\int_0^1 f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x \to 0$?

Of course, the simple way would be to just use Dominated Convergence (as the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals agree in this case) and conclude that the answer is affirmative. But this is not covered in the course. I haven't been able to think of other methods really; my first thought was to show that the functions are small on a large portion of $[0, 1]$ eventually. I wasn't really able to do this. Further, formalising that may require some measure theory, which is, again, not expected.

I asked the Prof about this. He wasn't able to get to a solution right way. He said his main aim, by giving the above problem, was to show that Riemann integrals are not so easy to work with as you'd initially believe. So, he's not very sure if it can actually be solved using the tools introduced in the course.

> Is there an elementary proof of the above statement?

PS: It is possible that this question is a duplicate; I did check a few questions but didn't find an equivalent one.

Comment: I don't have it handy, but I believe that this is an exercise in Chapter 2 of Rudin, and refers to a paper that proves it without using Lebesgue integration. It is not elementary.

Comment: @user296602: I'm not sure to which Rudin you're referring, but the result is false.

Comment: @TedShifrin With the additional assumption that $f_n$ has range contained in $[0, 1]$ it's true. And the Rudin I'm referring to is Real & Complex Analysis.

Comment: Oh, I missed the range limitation, @user296602, thanks. But please be a bit more explicit when an author has written numerous texts.

Comment: Some thoughts - It's easy to prove the result if we have $f_n$ converging to 0 uniformly. Hence, one way to proceed might be to reprove Egorov's theorem in the case of continuous functions. Another way is to construct a dominating function sequence $g_n$ that decreases to 0  in $n$ for each $x$, as Dini's Lemma then gives us uniform convergence again. Not sure if these are doable.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, Egorov's theorem was what I had in mind. I wasn't really able to proceed like I mentioned above. I didn't think of Dini's Lemma though. Taking $g_n = \sup_{m \geq n} f_m$ (pointwise) will do the trick I suppose. So, we just have to prove Dini's Lemma in an elementary fashion. I guess this can be done by translating the open cover definitions to the subsequences definitions. I'll try this line of thought. If you get it before me, do post the answer.

Comment: @DeeparajBhat I'm not sure that will work because $g_n$ may not be continuous.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Oh! Forgot to think about that. I guess we can smoothen it out with mollifiers or so. That'd still go beyond what is expected though. Thanks for your comment though, it was quite helpful.

Comment: For reference, this is Problem 10 in Chapter 2 of Rudin's "Real and complex analysis", third edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By assumption,
$$
[0,1] = \bigcap_{j\ge 1}\bigcup_{N\ge 1}\bigcap_{n\ge N}\{x:f_n(x) \le 1/j\}.
$$
By monotonicity of measure, for some $j > 1/\epsilon$ sufficiently large, we can pick a subset $E_j\subset[0,1]$ satisfying
$$
m(E_j) : = m(\{x : f_n(x)\le 1/j\ \text{eventually in $n$}\}) \ge 1-\epsilon.
$$
By monotonicity again, we can choose a good subset $G_j$ of $E_j$ with $m(G_j)\ge 1-2\epsilon$, and such that there exists an $N$ independent of $x\in G_j$ so that
$$
f_n(x)\le 1/j\quad\text{for all $n\ge N$}.
$$
Let $B_j := [0,1]\setminus G_j$, so that $[0,1] = G_j\sqcup B_j$, and  $m(B_j) < 2\epsilon$. For any $n$,
$$
\int f_n = \int_{G_j}f_n + \int_{B_j}f_n \le \int_{G_j}f_n + 2\epsilon.
$$
By definition of $G_j$, for all $n\ge N$,
$$
\int_{G_j}f_n \le (1/j)m(G_j) + 2\epsilon < 3\epsilon.
$$
Thus, $\int f_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Note that the continuity assumption is not used.